# Reducing a system of ordinary differential equations by imposing relations between the variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-function-theorem

Let's assume that we have the following system of O.D.E.
\begin{align}
    x' = f_1(x,y,z,v),\ y' = f_2(x,y,z,v),\ z' = f_3(x,y,z,v),\ v' = f_4(x,y,z,v)
\end{align}
for suitable smooth functions $f_1$, $f_2$, $f_3$ and $f_4$.

Let $\lambda$ be some nonzero constant and let's assume that
\begin{align}
    \lambda f_3(x,y,z,\lambda z) = f_4(x,y,z,\lambda z).
\end{align}
If one considers the `reduced' system of 0.D.E.
\begin{align}
    x' &= f_1(x,y,z,\lambda z)\ y' = f_2(x,y,z,\lambda z)\ z' = f_3(x,y,z,\lambda z)
\end{align}
then, any solution of the reduced system is a solution of the original system provided that $v=\lambda z$.

My question is the following. From the implicit function theorem (applied to the equation $\lambda f_3 = f_4$, as before) we know that
\begin{align}
    z = g(x,y),
\end{align}
for some function $g$.

If we consider the even smaller system of O.D.E.
\begin{align}
    x' = f_1(x,y,g(x,y),\lambda g(x,y))\ y' = f_2(x,y,g(x,y),\lambda g(x,y))
\end{align}
will any solution of the smallest system be a solution of the original system provided that $z = g(x,y)$ and $v = \lambda g(x,y)$?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! It will be a solution. Wherever you can find an [First Integral](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/First_integral) to your systems, it can be reduced in number of variables. If your system admits enough first integrals, it is called an [Integrable system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system) .